# Redirect URL including folder path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I have the following rewrite rule setup:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Now this works for redirecting domain.com/index.htm to domain2.com/index.htm  however it won't redirect any folders e.g.  domain.com/folder/ won't redirect to domain2.com/folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice: use proper lower/uppercase:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Then maybe you forgot the "L" for "Last rule".

When you say "it won't redirect any folders e.g. domain.com/folder/ won't redirect to domain2.com/folder/" please explain what it gives, what it should give, and what it give without the rewrite rules. Then I could help you further.

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Another useful tip is to use `curl -I http://example.com/foo` or `curl --include http://example.com/foo` to test your rules.  Doing this in a browser can result in several redirects happening with no hint that this is going on, leading to much confusion.

Comment: When I try view domain.com/folder/ it just does nothing, no redirect over to domain2.com, it just loads domain.com/folder/.  domain.com/index.htm redirects to domain2.com/index.htm though.

Comment: Looks like I had another .htaccess that was interfering with some folders.  Thanks again for all your help.